# Valuation in quadratic fields

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

Let $K/\mathbb Q$ ($K=\mathbb Q(\sqrt d)$, $d\in\mathbb Z$ square-free) be a quadratic field, $p$ a prime number. Assume that $p$ is inert in $K$. Let $n$ be a positive integer.
Is it true that for $A\in O_K\setminus\mathbb Z$ ($O_K$ is the ring of integers of $K$),
$v_p\left(\prod_{j=0}^{p^n-1}\limits(A-j)\right)$ is bounded when $n\to+\infty$.

Comment: What if $A = p\sqrt{d}$?

Comment: I don't understand your remark.  It looks like the quantity is bounded, isn't it?

Comment: Why is it bounded?

Comment: With more thoughts, it is not so obvious!! And even, I am surely wrong. I forgot to consider the $j$'s such that are exactly divided by $p$.